# UTF-8 encoding in Spring MVC, problem with FORMs

Tags: spring-mvc, character-encoding, forms

I have this in web.xml

```
   <filter>
        <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
        </filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

and at the top of file.jsp I have this:

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
```

in `<head>` this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

and characters other than latin-1 set from FORM with method POST are still not correct.

Comment: Your own answer is the best. please accept it

Comment: Why you are not accepting your own answer to help others?

Comment: he can't accept. Because his last seen here on stackoverflow shows Mar 3 '11 at 12:46 @NaeemShah

Answer (score 85):

I solved this.

That filter in web.xml must be first filter in file.

Comment: I had the same problem when submitting a web page using Spring and Romanina Characters. I totally missed that it could come because of the way Spring Forms use a different encoding then UTF-8. :) You save me. thx!

Comment: @Sangdol: The problem is that even when pageEncoding is specified to be UTF-8, the modern browsers no longer send the Accept-Encoding header when submitting POST requests (see http://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=572652, http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=112804) and the Servlet spec specifies Latin-1/ISO-8859-1 as default.
See also the Javadoc for CharacterEncodingFilter: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/CharacterEncodingFilter.html

Comment: If you have the problem with Spring security, you can look at that post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20863489/characterencodingfilter-dont-work-together-with-spring-security-3-2-0

Comment: he can't accept. Because his last seen here on stackoverflow shows Mar 3 '11 at 12:46  :p @gipinani

Comment: thank you so much this thing took too much to solve !

Answer (score 14):

I had similar problem. When I post a form and save it in DB, it is inserted as ?????? but if I manually insert to DB using the MySQL WorkBench it works fine.

I thought the problem is only in http request encoding. So, I almost implemented all recommendations I found about this issue like change **server.xml**, adding filter to **web.xml** and changing settings in MySQL config file **my.ini** but it does not solve my problem.

The problem was due to two things the **http request encoding** and the **JDBC connection**. For some reason MySQL is accepting data as ISO-8859-1 not as UTF-8.

So, I reverted all changes and I made below two changes:
**Change Tomcat server.xml as below:**

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443"  URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

**Change Jdbc connection properties as below:**

```
jdbc.driver_class=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/dB_Name?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password
```

The solution key here is adding **useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8**

**Add a filter like @jbb did in **web.xml**:**

```
<filter>
     <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
     <filter-class>
  org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
     </filter-class>
     <init-param>
  <param-name>encoding</param-name>
  <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
     </init-param>
     <init-param>
     <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
     <param-value>true</param-value>
     </init-param>
 </filter>

 <filter-mapping>
     <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
```

**If Thymeleaf is used, change viewResolver and TemplateResolver as below:**

```
viewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
viewResolver.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");

templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

Comment: You've made my day! `URIEncoding="UTF-8"` resolved for me!

Comment: i missed encoding-filter in web.xml , now it works like charm.

Comment: This:
`viewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
viewResolver.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");

templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");`

worked for me! Thank's a lot!

Answer (score 8):

Note that this works only for **POST** requests. If you want to code also **GET** requests (i.e. links with `<a href=...>`), you will have to modify your server's **server.xml** file, by adding `URIEncoding="UTF-8" useBodyEncodingForURI="true"` attributes in the `<Connector>` tag.

See : http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding

Comment: Spent a whole morning Googling this issue. Everyone was suggesting the URIEncoding property, first time I see useBodyEncodingForURI and it solved it for me, thank you!