# Spring form and controller UTF-8 bad encoding

Tags: post, spring-mvc, utf-8, character-encoding, hdiv

I have a problem with my UTF-8 encoding. My webapp uses french words that are correctly displayed in my jsp, but not in my controller after a POST.
For example, in my jsp I have:

> Prénom de mon père

and when I post the form, the controller gets:

> PrÃ©nom de mon pÃ¨re

The characterEncodingFilter is the first filter in the file as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141403/utf-8-encoding-in-spring-mvc-problem-with-forms)

Here is my jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!doctype html>
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles"         prefix="tiles" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"          prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"   prefix="form" %>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="fr">
    ...
    </head>

    <form:form class="form-horizontal" modelAttribute="AlimentationForm"
    action="${actionUrl}" method="POST">
    ...
         <form:input path="questions" class='input-xlarge' type='text' value='Prénom de mon père'/>
    </form>
```

My web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/web/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

And my application-config.xml

```
<beans:bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <beans:property name="basename">
        <beans:value>classpath:messages</beans:value>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</beans:bean>
```

I don't know what's wrong in my app or my configuration, have you got any idea?

Thank in advance.

EDIT: I'm using HDIV framework

Comment: What about adding "<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>" on jsp?

Comment: Done, but I didn't mentioned it. I've edited my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem actually came from HDIV framework version 2.1.2. A patch is available [here](https://github.com/hdiv/hdiv/issues/21) if you can't use the next release.

Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the JSP page encodes the data sent to the server properly. Try adding

```
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

to the top of your JSP as this ensures any data sent along http will get encoding correctly.

I believe the default http encoding is ISO-8859-1.

Comment: This line is already in my jsp file. How to change default http encoding on post ?

Comment: It wasn't before you edited it! Normally with a plain form you can do  something like <form accept-charset="utf-8"> not sure with a spring forms tag.