# CharacterEncodingFilter don't work together with Spring Security 3.2.0

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-java-config

I'm new to Spring MVC framework and I have got an issue that I can not resolve by myself. Everything started when I integrated spring security with my application, after that all unicode values from HTML form were not encoded (spring security works correctly). I came to conclusion that this is happening probably because my `DelegatingFilterProxy` is called as the first filter in the chain.

Here is my configuration that I thought will work, but it doesn't:

1)I'm extending AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer - from javadoc:

```
Registers the DelegatingFilterProxy to use the springSecurityFilterChain() before any
other registered Filter.
```

From that class I also override beforeSpringSecurityFilterChain method which regarding to javadoc:

```
Invoked before the springSecurityFilterChain is added.
```

So I thought this will be the best place to register CharacterEncodingFilter:

```
public class MessageSecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    protected void beforeSpringSecurityFilterChain(ServletContext servletContext) {
        FilterRegistration.Dynamic characterEncodingFilter = servletContext.addFilter("encodingFilter", new CharacterEncodingFilter());
        characterEncodingFilter.setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
        characterEncodingFilter.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");
        characterEncodingFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");
    }
}
```

But this do not work.

Another option I tired was to register filter through AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer class by overriding getServletFilters() method:

```
public class WebAppInitializer extends
        AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    //{!begin addToRootContext}
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { SecurityConfig.class, DatabaseConfig.class, InternationalizationConfig.class };
    }
    //{!end addToRootContext}

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { WebAppConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {

        CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);
        return new Filter[] { characterEncodingFilter};
    }
}
```

But this do not work neither. Does anyone come across the same issue or have got some ideas how to resolve this?

Here is my full configuration for the first option where I'm registering encoding filter through AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer:

```
@Order(1)
public class MessageSecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    protected void beforeSpringSecurityFilterChain(ServletContext servletContext) {
        FilterRegistration.Dynamic characterEncodingFilter = servletContext.addFilter("encodingFilter", new CharacterEncodingFilter());
        characterEncodingFilter.setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
        characterEncodingFilter.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");
        characterEncodingFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");
    }
}

@Order(2)
public class WebAppInitializer extends
        AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    //{!begin addToRootContext}
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { SecurityConfig.class, DatabaseConfig.class, InternationalizationConfig.class };
    }
    //{!end addToRootContext}

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { WebAppConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }
}

@EnableWebMvc
//@Import(value = {DatabaseConfig.class, InternationalizationConfig.class, SecurityConfig.class})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.ajurasz.controller", "com.ajurasz.service", "com.ajurasz.model"})
@Configuration
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public UrlBasedViewResolver viewResolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver urlBasedViewResolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        urlBasedViewResolver.setViewClass(TilesView.class);
        urlBasedViewResolver.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        return urlBasedViewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer() {
        TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer = new TilesConfigurer();
        tilesConfigurer.setDefinitions(new String[] {"/WEB-INF/tiles.xml"});
        return tilesConfigurer;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/**");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/documents/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/pdfs/documents/**");
    }

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver pageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver =
                new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver();
        pageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.setFallbackPageable(new PageRequest(0, 4, new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "id")));

        argumentResolvers.add(pageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver);
    }
}
```

**Dependencies:**

spring-mvc                 **3.2.5.RELEASE**

spring-security-config, spring-security-web, spring-security-core  **3.2.0.RELEASE**

I'm working on this under following link:
https://github.com/ajurasz/Manager

Comment: Be a good SO citizen and mark the correct answer.

Comment: You said you got this to work after re-installing Tomcat? Any more details?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have the same problem. My solution was to use a raw servlet filter:

```
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
      FilterRegistration.Dynamic encodingFilter = servletContext.addFilter("encoding-filter", new CharacterEncodingFilter());
      encodingFilter.setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
      encodingFilter.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");
      encodingFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");
}
```

Note that this problem only occures with Tomcat but not with Jetty.

Comment: I'll mark this answer as correct because it shows an alternative solution to fix character encoding issue outside web.xml. I'd also like to mention that overriding getServletMappings() method of AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer class  will make it to works. As you will see that approach was used by me but it started to work after re-installing tomcat.

Comment: I had the same problem and none of the above worked. Instead I removed the SecurityWebApplicationInitializer class and just added the spring security filter in the method getServletFilters.

Comment: This almost worked for me. It had no effect until I made sure that the CharacterEncodingFilter is the first in the filterChain that gets to handle the request. To make sure the characterEncodingFilter is first in the chain you need to change the middle argument in addMappingForUrlPatterns to false. The value false ensures that the CharacterEncodingFilter is the first filter in the chain, the value true adds the filter to the end of the filterChain.

Comment: Also occurs with wildfly 8

Answer (score 66):

We need to add CharacterEncodingFilter before filters who read request properties for the first time. There is securityFilterChain (stands second. after metrica filter) and we can add our filter inside it. The first filter (inside security chain) who reads properties is CsrfFilter, so we place CharacterEncodingFilter before it.

The short solution is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        CharacterEncodingFilter filter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        filter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        filter.setForceEncoding(true);
        http.addFilterBefore(filter,CsrfFilter.class);
        //rest of your code   
    }
//rest of your code
}
```

Comment: Exactly, Tried every other solution and this one works for me.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me. I would have expected Christian Nilsson's solution to work but in the context of Spring Security, it doesn't

Comment: It's sad but suggested solution is not working for me. I've tried all combinations I've found on the Internet and still looking for solution.

Comment: Grails 4.0.10 with native Spring Security has the same error: UTF8 entered form data will be presented in iso-8859-1. The above solution worked like a charm. Many thanks.

Answer (score 20):

I ran into the same issue recently and your first try is actually very close to the solution I ended up using (here's your code, fixed) :

```
public class MessageSecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
@Override
protected void beforeSpringSecurityFilterChain(ServletContext servletContext) {
    FilterRegistration.Dynamic characterEncodingFilter = servletContext.addFilter("encodingFilter", new CharacterEncodingFilter());
    characterEncodingFilter.setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
    characterEncodingFilter.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");
    characterEncodingFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
    }
}
```

The only difference is the second argument when adding filter mapping for url patterns. The [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/FilterRegistration.html#addMappingForServletNames%28java.util.EnumSet,%20boolean,%20java.lang.String...%29) for this parameter states :

> isMatchAfter - true if the given filter mapping should be matched after any declared filter mappings, and false if it is supposed to be matched before any declared filter mappings of the ServletContext from which this FilterRegistration was obtained

So setting it to false should cleanly solve your issue (without any XML involved).

Comment: This is the best non-web.xml solution.

Answer (score 15):

I don't know *what* exactly the problem is but I'd never configure such a simple filter inside Spring. Rather do it right in `web.xml` - easier to develop, understand and debug.

```
  <!-- Hint: http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding#Q8 -->
  <filter>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>encoding</param-name>
      <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

Important: configure this filter's mapping *before* the Spring Security filter chain (i.e. before the filter mapping for `DelegatingFilterProxy`).

Comment: Your answer is 100% valid as I tried this solution and it fixed my problem, but with this project I wanted to completely avoid web.xml (I should mention this in the question - sorry for not specifying this)

Comment: Configuring the encoding filter before delegating filter proxy is important. It resolved my issue that was persistent for lots of months. Now the app is working as expected with unicode.

Answer (score 2):

I have used

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        CharacterEncodingFilter filter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        filter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        filter.setForceEncoding(true);
        http.addFilterBefore(filter,CsrfFilter.class);
        //rest of your code   
    }
//rest of your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't like the answers posted so far because either use obscure Spring classes, or rely on implementation details.

In my opinion things should work by simply defining a standard `@Bean` with high `@Order`, so this is Boot's fault - but luckily everything works as expected (?) if we use a `FilterRegistrationBean` instead of a plain `Filter` (I'm using Boot 1.1.5):

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean() {
    FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
    registrationBean.setFilter(characterEncodingFilter);
    characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
    characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);
    registrationBean.setOrder(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
    registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");
    return registrationBean;
}
```