# How to handle OAuth2 authorization code with Spring OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter + AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails

Tags: java, spring, oauth, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to do an oauth2 authentication using Spring Security OAuth.

I've plugged an `OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter` to my security config, and with an `AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails`. I'm retrieving the authorization code, but the Oauth flow is broken, I'm not able to get the access_token.

Here is my configuration:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    /**
     *  Moved from com.myscript.backend.configuration.WebApp.java
     *  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20863489/characterencodingfilter-dont-work-together-with-spring-security-3-2-0             *
     */
    CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
    characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
    characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);
    http.addFilterBefore(characterEncodingFilter, CsrfFilter.class);


    String key = "**************************";
    ApiPersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices rememberMeServices = new ApiPersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices(key, userDetailsService, adminTokenRepository);

    // @formatter:off
    http
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint())
    .and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .rememberMe()
        .rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices)
        .tokenRepository(adminTokenRepository)
        .key(key)
        .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
    .and()
        .addFilterAfter(oauth2ClientContextFilter, SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.class)
        .addFilterBefore(ssoFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .formLogin()
        .loginProcessingUrl("/**/authentication/login*")
        .usernameParameter("email")
        .passwordParameter("password")
        .successHandler(new RestAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
        .failureHandler(new RestAuthenticationFailureHandler())
        .permitAll()
    .and()
        .logout()
        .invalidateHttpSession(true)
        .logoutSuccessHandler(new LogoutSuccessHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
                throws IOException, ServletException {
                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
            }
        })
        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**/authentication/logout*"))
        .permitAll()
    .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/authentication/**", ...)
        .permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
    .and()
        .anonymous();
    // @formatter:on
}

private Filter ssoFilter() {
    OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter ssoFilter = new OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter("/**/authentication/login/sso");
    final OAuth2RestTemplate template = new OAuth2RestTemplate(sso());
    ssoFilter.setRestTemplate(template);
    return ssoFilter;
}

@Bean
protected OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails sso() {
    AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails details = new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();
    details.setId("sso");
    details.setClientId("*******");
    details.setClientSecret("*******");
    details.setAccessTokenUri("http://sso.test.com/oauth/token");
    details.setUserAuthorizationUri("http://sso.test.com/oauth/authorize");
    details.setPreEstablishedRedirectUri("http://localhost:8894/api/v3.0/admin/authentication/login/sso");
    details.setScope(Arrays.asList("read", "write"));
    details.setUseCurrentUri(false);
    return details;
}
```

And at least I'm redirected to: http://localhost:8894/api/v3.0/admin/authentication?code=YjMXjl&state=ktv3am#