# Java, Spring, JSP encoding

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, utf-8

I've looked through alot of post on this topic but still not found a solution.

When I send data (url) from my JSP to my Spring controller it appears as 'fc-bayern-mÃ¼nchen-5'.  The umlaut is encoded in this way but I've tried to ensure my app is using UTF-8 encoding, which appears not to be working.

The URL in firefox shows as [http://localhost:8081/team/fc-bayern-münchen-5](http://localhost:8081/team/fc-bayern-m%C3%BCnchen-5)
and when pasted elsewhere shows as http://localhost:8081/team/fc-bayern-m%C3%BCnchen-5 which I think is expected for UTF-8.

I've tried using `URLDecoder.decode(url.getBytes(), "UTF-8")` but that didnt work either.

**JSP:**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <jsp:include page="../partialviews/globaheader.jsp" >
        <jsp:param name="title" value="Teams"/>
    </jsp:include>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<jsp:include page="../partialviews/menu.jsp"/>

<h3>Teams</h3>
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Short Name</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <c:forEach items="${teams}" var="team">
        <tr>
            <td><img class="smallBadge" src="/static/images/${team.getEncodedCrestUrl()}"/></td>
            <c:set var="url" value="${team.getTeamNameUrlFriendly()}-${team.id}" scope="request"/>
            <td><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/team/${url}">${team.name}</a></td>
            <td>${team.shortName}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**Controller:**

```
@Transactional
@RequestMapping(value = "/team/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getBttsTips(@PathVariable final String id, final Model model) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    final int teamId = Integer.valueOf(id.substring(id.lastIndexOf("-")+1, id.length()));
    final String teamName = id.substring(0, id.lastIndexOf("-"));
    final Team team = teamService.findById(teamId);

    if (team == null || !team.getTeamNameUrlFriendly().equals(teamName)){
        return "error/404";
    }
    final List<Fixture> allFixtures = fixtureService.findAllFixturesByTeam(team);
    final List<Fixture> homeFixtures = fixtureService.findHomeFixturesByTeam(team);
    final List<Fixture> awayFixtures = fixtureService.findAwayFixturesByTeam(team);

    model.addAttribute("allFixtures", allFixtures);
    model.addAttribute("homeFixtures", homeFixtures);
    model.addAttribute("awayFixtures", awayFixtures);
    model.addAttribute("team", team);
    return "team/teamDetail";
}
```

**SecurityConfig:**

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
final CharacterEncodingFilter filter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
filter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
filter.setForceEncoding(true);
http.addFilterBefore(filter,CsrfFilter.class);
```

Thanks

**Update**
I switched to a Jetty server and it seems to be working fine with that.  Although I wanted to use Tomcat, I had tried to change the encoding in the Tomcat server.xml for the connector but even that didn't work.

**Final Update**
I had to use `URIEncoding="UTF-8" useBodyEncodingForURI="true"` in my Tomcat server.xml.  Without the `useBodyEncodingForURI="true"` it wouldn't work.
Post 5 here [UTF-8 encoding in Spring MVC, problem with FORMs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141403/utf-8-encoding-in-spring-mvc-problem-with-forms) helped me.

Comment: lets 1st try to put this within the head section of yourjsp file : <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset="utf-
8">

Comment: @Georgesvanhoutte yeah its already there.

Comment: Its maven I'm using

Comment: and your class is marked with the @Configuration ?

Comment: Yes I have the @Configuration annotation included

Answer (score 0):

`CharacterEncodingFilter` only works on POST request.So you need to send your data by post instead of get.If you keep in get,the following method you can try:

1. Edit server.xml in tomcat conf folder,put an attribute `URIEcoding="utf-8"` in Connector element.
2. convert url by `new String(url.getBytes("iso-8859-1"),"utf-8")`

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get it going but I had to add this line into the server.xml.  URIEncoding="UTF-8" useBodyEncodingForURI="true".  Without useBodyEncodingForURI attribute it wouldn't work.